# HBase rename row

Tags: hbase

I need to be able to rename row key in HBase and as my research goes, there's no supported way of doing it. The only way to do it is manually, through following steps:

- Get row under old key
- Put row under new key
- Delete row under old key

What bugs me is the following - what if something fails in between? For example, I don't want to get into situation of having a same row under two different row keys.

Is there some kind of transactional way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

- There are no transactions in HBase
- And yes, row key is immutable, you cannot change it.

The only way I might see is perform some extra validation or checks on client side. For ex.:

- mark old row as deleted (add some column to old row soft delete = true and new row id = ???)
- create new row with new key
- delete row with old row id.

Based on created flags you can rollback or complete operation if smith went wrong.